# Calling Craft Console Commands from Plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugins, request, console

I am in the process of building a plugin that has a controller that accepts a HTTP request. If the token and request are valid, I would like to call a Craft Console Command from within the plugin (e.g. `gc/run` or `resave/entries`).

The equivalent would be using the CLI for call the command `./craft gc/run` but from a controller.

How would I call the command from my plugins HTTP controller?

Comment: Do you need to call some build in command or your own? Usually I wrap functions in Service Classes so I can call them both from controllers and/or console commands.

Comment: I’m calling a built in command. Running in a Docker environment so I cannot SSH into the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Yii treats console commands like requests, you need to perform the following steps to execute a Craft console command from within a plugin:

1. Within your plugin, set the namespace to match the commands namespace
2. Call a run action from your plugin, and pass the route name/params

```
    MyPlugin::$plugin->getInstance()->controllerNamespace = 'craft\console\controllers';

    $command = MyPlugin::$plugin->getInstance()->runAction('gc/run');
```